# Querying AzureAD Graph extension attributes with Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am in the process of migrating away from Azure AD Graph API to Microsoft Graph since it is now deprecated. Previously it was possible to access extended properties against a user using `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` `.GetExtendedProperties();` call e.g:

```
var client = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await GetToken());
var user = await client.Users["user id..."].ExecuteAsync();
var properties = user.GetExtendedProperties();
```

I need to replicate this with equivalent calls in `Microsoft Graph`.

I have looked at the [schemaExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview#schema-extensions?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5000174) endpoint, e.g:

GET all extensions:

`/v1.0/schemaExtensions`

But this doesn't appear to return the same extensions data that the AD Graph Client did.

GET user with ext:

`v1.0/users/[user id]?$expand=extensions&$select=id,extension_[application id]_myExtension,onPremisesExtensionAttributes,displayName,jobTitle,identities`

Where `extension_[application id]_myExtension` is an example extension in the format:

`extension_appid_extensionname`

And this doesn't return the custom extension data for the user (other properties work fine however).

How can we migrate extended properties from AD Graph Client to Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SchemaExtensions** is different from **extensionProperty**. What you mentioned should be [extensionProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in Microsoft Graph.

You can use [List extensionProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get all extensions.

Your request `v1.0/users/[user id]?$expand=extensions&$select=id,extension_[application id]_myExtension,onPremisesExtensionAttributes,displayName,jobTitle,identities` should be correct.

Please make sure that the `application id` should remove all `-`. The extension property format is `extension_[application id without "-"]_myExtension`.

For example:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,extension_6d****fbf1fe4bc38a5a145520****89_policy,displayName
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(id,extension_6d****fbf1fe4bc38a5a145520****89_policy,displayName)/$entity",
    "id": "98****c9-f062-48e2-8ced-22cb68****ce",
    "displayName": "Allen Wu",
    "extension_6d****fbf1fe4bc38a5a145520****89_policy": "readwrite"
}
```

[image]

The C# code sample:

```
var user = await graphClient.Users["98****c9-f062-48e2-8ced-22cb6****ce"]
    .Request()
    .Select("id,extension_6d****fbf1fe4bc38a5a145520****89_policy,displayName")
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be exactly what I need. Is it only available on the `/me/` endpoint though? I'm getting an error `Request_ResourceNotFound` when calling the list endpoint `/applications/{id]/extenstionProperties`

Comment: @DGibbs This error occurs when the `{id}` is incorrect. It should be the object id (not application id) of the app registration. Please check.

Comment: Yep that was my issue, thanks very much for this!