# Read b2c extension attribute using Graph API in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

We are using the Graph API in C# to read data from AD about users setup in B2C.

We have a number of extension attributes setup in the b2c environment, and we want to be able to read the values of these attributes for users in our C# application.

We can make a successful request to get details on the user using:

```
graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Request().Select("id,displayName").GetAsync();
```

Which returns the details on the attributes specified.

However, we can't find an option for getting the extension attribute values back with this request. We have included the name of the attribute using the guid of the application storing the attributes, but the attributes are not returned.

We have also tried the following request, which returns the response of "Extension with given id not found":

```
var extensionDetails = graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Extensions["extension_{guidWithDashesRemoved}_{attributeName}"].Request().GetAsync();
```

We are able to do this successfully in Postman with the following get request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,givenName,postalCode,extension_{guidWithDashesRemoved}_{attributeName}
```

Has anyone been able to get the extension attribute values back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first code is correct. You need to add the extension property into the `select` query parameter.

```
var user = await graphServiceClient.Users[userId]
    .Request()
    .Select("id,extension_{guidWithDashesRemoved}_{attributeName},displayName")
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: I thought I'd tried this yesterday. I've now reran the code with this exact setup and I'm still not getting the extension attribute value back. Would the value be held under Extensions of user? Something like `var value = user.Extensions;`? However `user.Extensions` is empty.

Comment: @penguin178 `{guidWithDashesRemoved}` should be the `application id without "-" `. Please have a check with it. See details from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050611/querying-azuread-graph-extension-attributes-with-microsoft-graph?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: Thanks @AllenWu that link helped me get the details back. The query to list the extension properties was the final clue that got me over the line!

Comment: @penguin178 Great! If my answer is helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you:)

Comment: @AllenWu I tried doing same thing in JAVA however I am still getting NULL for all extensionAttribute1-15 under "onPremisesExtensionAttributes"

Comment: @AllenWu This is what I have in my code - .select("extension_41c9c83f09534556b4085c6f3abf7f85_tenant, onPremisesExtensionAttributes, displayName, userType") and when I am doing user.displayName or user.userType I am getting correct data but when I am doing user.onPremisesExtensionAttributes for all extensionAttribuet I saw NULL when i was debugging

Comment: @penguin178 can you please share what you mean by "the query to list the extension properties"? I have the exact same code as suggested but the .Extensions property is coming back as null for me.